# Глюки background в Listview getView() при использовании SimpleAdapter filter

Tags: java, android

Сложный вопрос получился.

Я использую `listView` с `simpleAdapter`. Для задания фона строчек переопределил `getView`, а для фильтрации списка использую `lvadapter.getFilter().filter(s)`

При первичной загрузке списка, все бэкграунды правильно и красиво размещаются, а когда начинаю фильтровать, строчки списка красятся как попало.

```
lvadapter = new SimpleAdapter(
     ClientsListActivity.this, clientsList,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2, new String[] {
         TAG_NAME, TAG_PHONE
     },
     new int[] {
         android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2
     }) {
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) {
         View result = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
         if (position == 0) {
             result.setBackgroundColor(0x448FCC85);
         } else {
             // set another background ... this is the default background, you have to provide this because the views are reused
         }
         HashMap < String, Object > itemHashMap = (HashMap < String, Object > ) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
         boolean vip = ((boolean) itemHashMap.get("vip"));
         if (vip) {
             result.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(245, 233, 234));
         }
         return result;
     }
 };
```

Что делать не знаю, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам нужно не только закрашивать нужные (vip), но и принудительно восстанавливать прежний цвет в "ненужных" (!vip) - используйте конструкцию `if- else` для того, чтобы устанавливать оба цвета для айтема.

Comment: Супер, спасибо помогло! Век живи век учись!

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно не только закрашивать нужные (`vip`), но и принудительно восстанавливать прежний цвет в "ненужных" (`!vip`) - используйте конструкцию `if - else` для того, чтобы устанавливать оба цвета для айтема.
Это связано с тем, что при построении списка, каждый айтем многократно переиспользуется в других позициях и в позицию `!vip` может попасть тот, который ранее был в позиции `vip` (и наоборот):

```
if (vip) {
          result.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(<vip_color>));
         }
  else {
        result.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(<normal_color>));
       };
```